# Firestore listeners won't unsubscribe - VUE JS 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, unsubscribe

```
//Environment:

//Vue 3
//Vite
//Firebase V9
//Pinia** (For state management)
```

Hi!, I'm just trying to unsubscribe from firestore listeners from from Pinia Actions... for this matter I'll give a brief example of how is it set it up.

So first in my Pinia Store, I have defined a property where all the listeners (onSnapshot) are stored in order to access the unsubscribe function later from anywhere in my application.

```
    //Pinia store: frontDesk.ts
    
    import {defineStore} from 'pinia'
    import {db} from "/@src/firebase/config";
    import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot, doc, getDoc, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";
    
    import {commonStore} from "/@src/stores/stores";
    
    export const useFrontDeskStore = defineStore({
      id: 'frontDesk',
      state: () => ({
        ...
    
        listeners: <any>{
          ...
          getAvailability: () => null,
          ...
        }
      }),
      ...
      actions: {
        ...
        async getAvailability() {
          const q = query(collection(db, commonStore.selectedHotel, "guest", "reservations"), where('noShow', '==', false), where('cancelled', '==', false), orderBy("checkinDate", "desc"));
          this.listeners.getAvailability = onSnapshot(q, (docSnapshot) => {
            commonStore.masterLoader = true
            this.loadingAvailability = true
            this.reservations.splice(0, this.reservations.length)
            this.occupiedRooms.splice(0, this.occupiedRooms.length)
            docSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              const data = doc.data()
              if (rangesOverlaps([this.dateRange?.start, this.dateRange!.end], [firestoreToDate(data.checkinDate), firestoreToDate(data.checkoutDate)])){
                this.reservations.push(data)
                this.occupiedRooms.push(parseInt(data.roomNumber), ...data.extra_rooms)
              }
            })
            this.getBlockedRooms()
            commonStore.masterLoader = false
          });
        },
        ...
      }
    })
```

Then after checking for user inactivity, I access the unsubscribe function like this:

```
    //FrontDesk.vue
    //IDLE
    ...
    import { useIdle } from '@vueuse/core'
    const { idle, lastActive } = useIdle(5000) // 5 seconds (for testing purposes)
    
    watch(idle, val => {
      idleAction(val)
    })
    
    const idleAction = async (isIdle) => {
      if (isIdle) {
        console.log("Inactivity detected, stopping listeners to save some money")
        await frontDeskStore.listeners.getAvailability()
      } else {
        console.log("Activity detected, re-activating listeners for realtime updates")
        await frontDeskStore.getAvailability()
      }
    }
    ...
```

Everything seems to go through with no errors, but then from another client I make some change after the unsubscribe have been fired, and keep getting the real-time updates.

Is there anything I'm missing here?